# C++ Searching CSV file from inputted string

Tags: c++, visual-studio, csv

I am trying to create a program that will load the CSV file and based upon the inputted word search through the file and return any lines that contain the word. The CSV file is a mass download of tweets and has the following columns:

- Date & Time Created
- The Tweet

The tweets are also surrounded by b'TWEET TEXT HERE' so would need to remove the b' ' from when it printed out. I am unable to change anything to do with the CSV file sadly so cant manually remove it. The issues I am having are:

1. Listing the total amount of tweets within the file the program just freezes
2. Removing the b' ' from the tweets
3. The else statement causes "not found" to be constantly printed

Code I currently have that is returning the tweets that contain the inputted word but also the false positive.

[image: The current output when running the below code]

The current output when running the below code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string token;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("sampleTweets.csv");

    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File opened successfully" << "\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error opening file" << "\n";
    }

    cout << "Enter search word: ";
    cin >> token;
    "\n";

    string line;
    while (getline(fin, line)) {
        if (line.find(token) != string::npos) {
            cout << line << endl;
        } else {
        cout << token << " not found" << endl;
    }
    }

    fin.close();
    char anykey;
    cout << "press any key";
    cin >> anykey;
    return 0;

}
```

Code I was using for counting total tweets

```
int count = 0;
char str[140];

while (!fin.eof())
{
    fin.getline(str, 140);
    count++;
}

cout << "Number of lines in file are " << count;
```

Any help on this would be amazing as I am quite new to C++ and not sure where to go from here!

Comment: Why are you unconditionally running `cout << token << " not found" << endl;`?

Comment: Ah that would explain the fact it always prints that out...

Comment: cin >> token;    "\n";  I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but it is wrong.

Comment: @willll This is taking the users input for what they wish to search for.

Comment: Exactly what do you want the output line to look like?

Comment: I would ant the output to be: DATE/TIME Tweet

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `"b"` with `erase`:

```
if (line.find(token) != string::npos){
  int n= line.find(",");
  line.erase(n+1, 3);
  cout << line << endl;
}
```

and you can count the lines inside the `while` loop:

```
int count = 0;
while (getline(fin, line)) {
  ++count;
  ...
}
```

**EDIT:** you can remove the extra quotes and commas like so:

```
line[n] = ' '; // change comma int space
line.erase(n+1, 4); // remove "b""
line.resize(line.size()-5); // remove trailing """,,
```

Comment: Thank you for that it removed the b however there are still lots of commas and " that I would ideally like to remove as well. Currently the output is looking like this [Gyazo Capture](https://gyazo.com/b300b0a56d3dce221b5250351d9783dc)

Comment: @KaiJones: That's why I asked about the output line.

Comment: Sorry I thought that I had replied earlier my mistake. Do you have any idea why the else loop is being constantly ran even when the it should be?

Comment: @KaiJones: Yes, but you must solve that yourself. You misunderstood the logic of loops and conditionals when you wrote that code, and being told the answer will do you no good. I suggest you experiment with much simpler programs that use `while`, `if` and `else`.